# Cargar páginas desde un google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script-html-service

tengo un google sheets con Apps script y estoy tratando de crear una webapp con 4 paginas html, y no se como acceder a cada una de ellas?

```
/* index.html */
Bootstrap demo Pedidos Clientes Productos Estado document.getElementById("header-navbar").addEventListener("click", navbarClicked);

function navbarClicked(e) {
    if (e.target.matches(".nav-link")) {
        activarNavbar(e.target.id);
        loadPage(e.target.id);
        // Utilizamos la función loadPage para cargar la página correspondiente 
    }
}

function activarNavbar(navbarLinkId) {
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
        navLink.classList.remove("active");
    }) const activeNavLink = document.getElementById(navbarLinkId);
    activeNavLink.classList.add("active");
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, lecturas recomendadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.